# Mutex example with microsoft app

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

Very resently i was asked question in a telephonic interview about Synchronization object Mutex..i was asked to name a microsoft (mentioned as "famous") app that makes use of mutex as a synchronisation object . Is there a way to know what synchronisation object a app. uses..Please let me know if anyone knows .. Thanks in advnce

Comment: Mutexes are used internally in a huge number of functions. Any application that allocates memory using the standard allocator uses mutexes.

Comment: I'd say just about *everything* that Microsoft puts out would use mutexes. If they want a specific product, Windows or Office. Frankly, that was a dumb question.

Comment: @NikB.i too felt so...but the way the interviewer put that question made me wonder..specifically termed it as famous microsoft app..felt may be i did not know the answer but there is a answer

Comment: If so, then likely the interviewer knew, or thought he knew, some obscure piece of trivia and assumed that it should be known by anyone else who was as smart as he was.

Comment: If you really want to know which among a specific group of applications use mutexes, look at the import tables of them (with their DLLs) to see which import `CreateMutex` (or variations thereof). Not clear whether you may also want to include `InitializeCriticalSection` and company as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can see which synchronization objects an app uses using [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx). Click on the Process you're interested in and in the **View->Lower Pane View** menu select **Handles**. Mutexes are listed under **Type** as **Mutant**.